# How to get patterns from text file in unix and formating them into a table

Tags: parsing, unix, awk

I need to parse .conf file in Unix system to get the bold below content:

```
[sub_suffix-324]
; generated by mod_identity
exten => int,1,GoSub(mdc_template-3,s,1)
exten => int,n(next_380),Return()
; default action for busy
exten => ext,1,GoSub(mdc_template-3,s,1)
exten => ext,n,Set(PRI_CAUSE=17)
exten => ext,n,HangUp(17)
exten => ext,n(back),Return()
```

After taking the output to another file(not sure if we can do this directly) as below:

```
[sub_suffix-324]
exten => int,1,GoSub(mdc_template-3,s,1)
exten => ext,1,GoSub(mdc_template-3,s,1)
```

I need to depend on this output to generate the below format, I mean if we find

> template-3

then use it in a condition to see if there is

> int or ext

in the same line and output yes if condition true:

Extension    int_voicemail   ext_voicemail

324          yes            yes

I was trying to use awk command but with no luck how to proceed :D

```
#!/usr/bin/awk -f

/^\[sub_suffix-/ {

  print $0
  next
}

/mdc_template/ {
flag=1
x=$0
next
}
```

Hint: the file contains multiple occurrences of this snippet, so the output will be as a csv file format!!.

Any help is appreciated !!
Thanks

Comment: It would be better to not modify your input for the question, but additionally show exactly what the output should look like - and what your awk command looks like.

Comment: The precise input, the desired output, and the rationale behind the output is all unclear.

Comment: Your only stated requirement is `Since the yes under int/ext_voicemail determined if the bold content corresponding to each one(int,ext) exist if not set to No.` which unfortunately doesn't mean anything in English. Please edit your question to clarify best you can and include concise sample input and expected output.

Answer (score 0):

Using arrays to test `int` and `ext` conditions, and a counter for the `suffix` blocks :

```
/^\[sub_suffix-/ {
sub_suffix[++n_suffixes]=$0
is_int_mdc_template[n_suffixes]="no"
is_ext_mdc_template[n_suffixes]="no"
}

/exten => int.*mdc_template/ {
is_int_mdc_template[n_suffixes]="yes"
int_mdc_template[n_suffixes]=$0
}

/exten => ext.*mdc_template/ {
is_ext_mdc_template[n_suffixes]="yes"
ext_mdc_template[n_suffixes]=$0
}

END {
for (i=1; i<=n_suffixes; i++) {
  print sub_suffix[i], is_int_mdc_template[i], is_ext_mdc_template[i]
}
}
```

You could then use one of `substr`, `match`, `gsub` or `gensub` functions to extract the `suffix` part that you want.